# Why do I have Error In This Command python manage.py shell?

Tags: python, django

I use `Django 1.6`. I edit my `models.py` like this:

(I follow this link : [tutorial01](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) )

```
from django.db import models
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
                return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
               return self.choice_text
```

When I want execute this command I got error.

```
python manage.py shell
```

My error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
399, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242,
 in run_from_argv
 self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 285,
 in execute
 output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 415,
 in handle
 return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py",
 line 70, in handle_noargs
 get_models()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 232, in
 get_models
 self._populate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 75, in
_populate
self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 99, in
load_app
models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in im
port_module
__import__(name)
  File "G:\Programing\Django\Project\mysite\polls\models.py", line 7
def __str__(self):
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I thinks somethings in  this line is `def __str__(self):    return self.question` rong?

Comment: Try `python -tt models.py`, I think you're mixing spaces and tabs.

Comment: When I run your command i get this error : G:\Programing\Django\Project\mysite\polls>python -tt models.py
  File "models.py", line 7
    def __str__(self):
                     ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: Your code in the post is mixing tabs and spaces. *Don't*. Stick to spaces only, configure your editor to expand tabs to spaces for you.

Comment: @loup: Right, that's because you mixed tabs and spaces and did so inconsistently. Use your text editor to *replace* tabs with spaces, and fix the indentation.

Comment: @loup: also, are you using Python 3? If not, stick to `def __unicode__(self)` instead of `def __str__(self)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `def __str__` needs to be at the same indentation level as the rest of the class body.  Ensure that the contents of the class body and the def are all indented by 4 spaces.  You are mixing tabs and space indentations, which confuses the parser.  Avoid using tabs for indentation - just stick to 4 spaces for each level.  Your editor should have an option to insert 4 spaces when you press the tab key.

Comment: that wont lead to indentation error, while mixed tabs/spaces will

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your text editor. For me I used Notepad++ where the tab in the Notepad++ is not the same as in the tab for Python. So editing the code in Python's own text editor helps.

Secondly remove the line gap before

```
     def str(self):
```

Your code should look like this:

```
   
    from django.db import models

    class Poll(models.Model):
        question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        def __str__(self):
             return self.question

    class Choice(models.Model):
        poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
        choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        def __str__(self):
              return self.choice_text
```